# Filter out rows not columns depending on values in the row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that will filter out rows not columns depending on values in the row. E.g.:

```
apple   banana  pear    lime
lime    lime    lime    apple
pear    pear    pear    lime
pear    banana  lime    lime
apple   apple   apple   apple
```

So if I filter the above example for `apple` I get the first, second and last rows remaining.

Comment: Definitely possible. Post the code you've tried with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try :

```
Sub Filter_By_Rows()
Dim StrToLookFor As String, _
    ToHide As Boolean, _
    LastCol As Integer, _
    Ws As Worksheet

StrToLookFor = InputBox("Hide the rows not containing that value :")
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastCol = Ws.Cells(1, Ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If StrToLookFor <> vbNullString Then
    For i = 2 To Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ToHide = True
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            If InStr(1, Ws.Cells(i, j), StrToLookFor) Then
                ToHide = False
                Exit For
            Else
            End If
        Next j
        Ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = ToHide
    Next i
Else
End If
```

Or this version for multiple strings :

```
Sub Multi_Filter_By_Rows()
Dim StrToLookFor As String, _
    ToHide As Boolean, _
    LastCol As Integer, _
    Ws As Worksheet, _
    A() As String

'StrToLookFor = InputBox("Hide the rows not containing these values (separated with '/') :")
StrToLookFor = "apple/banana"
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastCol = Ws.Cells(1, Ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If StrToLookFor <> vbNullString Then
    If InStr(1, StrToLookFor, "/") Then
        A = Split(StrToLookFor, "/")
        For i = 2 To Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ToHide = True
            For k = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
                For j = 1 To LastCol
                    If InStr(1, Ws.Cells(i, j), A(k)) Then
                        ToHide = False
                        GoTo HideNow
                    Else
                    End If
                Next j
            Next k
HideNow:
            Ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = ToHide
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 2 To Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ToHide = True
            For j = 1 To LastCol
                If InStr(1, Ws.Cells(i, j), StrToLookFor) Then
                    ToHide = False
                    Exit For
                Else
                End If
            Next j
            Ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = ToHide
        Next i
    End If
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works is there any way to re edit the code so instead of a message box popping up you put multiple values in the code. I tried getting rid of =inputbox... and instead put array("apple", "banana") but it gives me error 13 type mismatch

Comment: What do you mean by multiple values? To test the presence of multiple different strings at the same time? If it is, give the edit a try! (in few seconds) ;)

Comment: I mean in my above sheet if apple or banana appear in the line then it shows that row. So only row 3 is hidden. I need it so you define what the values are inside the code (apple or banana)and you don't get a pop up.

Comment: Give the second one a try! ;)

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay your program works thanks for all the help

Comment: @Lucky01 : Glad I could help! ;) As you are new to SO, just a **few pointers** : When your problem is solved, you can **validate the answer by clicking in the tick** right under the up/down vote arrows. **Use up/down votes on each posts(Q or A) that you find useful/useless(or bad quality)**. And take a look : stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve